# How to change ft_boolean_syntax for mysql?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, phabricator

I want to change the search behavior of MariaDB/MySQL to use with Phabricator by adapting the variable ft_boolean_syntax.

As suggested by Phabricator

> To change this setting, add this to your my.cnf file (in the [mysqld]
>   section) and then restart mysqld:
>
> `ft_boolean_syntax=' |-><()~*:""&^'`

I tried to change the my.cnf file but mysql does not start with these changes.

`systemctl status mysql.service`

returns

`[ERROR] Invalid ft-boolean-syntax string:`

It seems to me as MySQL only sees the first character of the ft_boolean_string (which is a space).

MariaDB/MySQL version:

`mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.0.21-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1`

Any ideas how to solve this issue?

Comment: works for me. did you place it in the wrong section? place it twice? ... what does `grep ft_bool /etc/mysql/my.cnf` give?

Comment: grep in /etc/my.cnf shows only my own added entry: 
# ft_boolean_syntax=' |-><()~*:""&^'
i have put the entry in the [mysqld] section. when i remove the comment, i get the error i described above.

Answer (score 1):

I found the rules for changing the value in the MySQL documentation:

> if you want to change `ft_boolean_syntax`, the replacement value **must be 14 characters**
>   
> *- [source](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_ft_boolean_syntax)*